# Ignore pattern with speciefic word in it

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got the following code:

```
var one = "What a lovely puppy! 
    Is it 
    a beagle?",

    two = "You've got a lovely funny beagle!",

    three = "Where's my lovely dog? Where's my little beagle?";

var target = (".* lovely(?!funny).* beagle.*");
```

What I need is to "catch" words between `lovely` and `beagle`. If there's word `funny` between my "catch" boundaries (var `two`), the method
`match()` should ignore it.

In other words, it should check for matches all phrases from `lovely` to `beagle`, which involve no word `funny`.

My var target seems to be written incorrect.

I expect:

```
 one.match(target) //return: "puppy! Is it a"
 two.match(target) //must be ignored, because of word "funny"
 three.match(target) //return: "dog? Where's my little"
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: First of all, you have tagged this question with Javascript, but your code is not Javascript. It looks like a bastardized C#. Javascript has test, exec, etc and no multiline strings. C# has @"multiline" strings and Match methods.

Considering this is Javascript, take a look at http://xregexp.com/ for a more flexible syntax that also covers strings with newlines in it.

Test your regular expression here: http://www.regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to join the repeated test for `funny` and the `.*`. Try

```
lovely(?:(?!funny).)*beagle
```

[Check it out here at regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/fO9pD7/1)

Regards

Comment: Console returns SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Of course, because this `(:?` contains a typo. Also, a regex should be declared as a regex literal: `var regex = /lovely(?:(?!funny).)*beagle/;`

Comment: Yeah, now I see TNX!

Comment: And it is also very inefficient. Use this: `/lovely (?:(?!funny)[\S\s]*?) beagle/ig`

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex FYI Your regex doesn't match the OP's criteria "word funny between my 'catch' boundaries". [Check this.](https://regex101.com/r/eC8dB1/1) Your RE only works if `funny` is the first word. If that were the case, it should be `lovely (?!funny)[\S\s]*? beagle`.

Comment: You are right: https://jsfiddle.net/v0fu23cr/1/ the pattern should be `/lovely(?:(?!.*funny)[\s\S]*?)beagle/ig`, which is not more efficient that the solution. However, the solution provided in the answer doesn't work on multiline strings. Check out the `[\s\S]` thing that solved it.

Comment: 'lovely taifunny beagle' should not be matching.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make a per character check for the first letter, then check for 'funny' if current letter is an inital `f`:

```javascript
var regex = /\blovely\b([^f]|\Bf|f(?!unny\b))+\bbeagle\b/;
```